# Why do the ":" not sit on the top in layout files?

Tags: android, android-layout

small problem here:

This is my code of the layout in question:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <EditText
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="00"
            android:textColorHint="#2f8677"
            android:textColor="#2f8677"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:id="@+id/txtMinutes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:text=":"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textColor="#2f8677"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="00"
            android:textColorHint="#2f8677"
            android:textColor="#2f8677"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:id="@+id/txtSeconds"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text=":"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textColor="#2f8677"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="00"
            android:textColorHint="#2f8677"
            android:textColor="#2f8677"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:id="@+id/txtTimerMicroSeconds"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Why are the ":" sitting on the bottom and the EditTexts are on top? Both are (obviously) supposed to be on the same hight :(

Another little thing: See that little bar to the left of the first EditText? It is there because this is an edit text and you can "type" things into it. But I don't want it to show- How do I get this to go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some issues in your `android:gravity`, you can use `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to align your widgets with each other.

See the result here:

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="100"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMinutes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="00"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#2f8677"
        android:textColorHint="#2f8677"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text=":"
        android:textColor="#2f8677"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSeconds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="00"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#2f8677"
        android:textColorHint="#2f8677"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text=":"
        android:textColor="#2f8677"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtTimerMicroSeconds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="00"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#2f8677"
        android:textColorHint="#2f8677"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: otherwise add your parent code as it is not complete code

Comment: @nomag this is my parent code, and the code I got from OP.

Comment: thanks again, but it just doesnt look the way it looks here. for my, one of the ":" is way up, the other one is way down. the 00 are alligned ..?

Comment: I made an edit, please try this or post a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code: 
I have removed layout_top from textview for alignment.
And you may use `android:cursorVisible="false"` to hide edittext cursor.
If you do not want to allow editing, then use `textview` instead of `Edittext`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="100"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <EditText
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:hint="00"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:textColorHint="#2f8677"
    android:textColor="#2f8677"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtMinutes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:gravity="top"
    android:text=":"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textColor="#2f8677"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<EditText
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:hint="00"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:textColorHint="#2f8677"
    android:textColor="#2f8677"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtSeconds"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text=":"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:textColor="#2f8677"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<EditText
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:hint="00"
    android:textColorHint="#2f8677"
    android:textColor="#2f8677"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtTimerMicroSeconds"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```